# Extend base Array class in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, extend

I have a custom array class that extends the base array class. I have a custom method for ease of use

```
export class ExampleArray extends Array {
    includesThing(thing) {
        ...

        return false
    }
}
```

However the existing methods of `filter`, `map` etc return an instance of an array. I would like to return an instance of `ExampleArray` with these methods.

I can find the interface for these methods, but not their implementation. How do I call the parent method and return my custom EampleArray instead? Something like the following

```
export class ExampleArray extends Array {
    filter() {

    result = Array.filter()
    array = new ExampleArray()
    array.push(...result)

    return array
}
```

Or is this even the correct way to extend an Array to make a custom array?

Comment: I think you might have better success using object composition

Comment: Good question. I agree with @Rafael. You could have an array object as a property in ExampleArray. And, write glue logic to ferry data between Array and ExampleArray.  i.e. If the method does not exist in Array then its the custom implementation else wrap results from Array methods to return ExampleArray type.

Comment: Could you provide an example of what you mean?

Comment: By using .prototype you can extend Array and add your custom method or override exist one.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You will need to *shadow* the existing `.filter` and `.map` so that, when called on an instance of `ExampleArray`, your *new* functions will be called, rather than the  `Array.prototype` functions. Inside `ExampleArray`, you can access `super.map` and `super.filter` in order to get to the `Array.prototype` methods. For example:

```js
class ExampleArray extends Array {
  constructor(...args) {
    super(...args);
  }
  hasMoreThanTwoItems() {
    // example custom method
    return this.length > 2;
  }
  isExampleArray() {
    return true;
  }
  
  // Shadow Array.prototype methods:
  filter(...args) {
    return new ExampleArray(
      // Spread the result of the native .filter into a new ExampleArray instance:
      ...super.filter.apply(this, args)
    );
  }
  map(...args) {
    return new ExampleArray(
      ...super.map.apply(this, args)
    );
  }
}

const exampleArray = new ExampleArray(3, 4, 5, 6, 7);

// true, filtering will result in 3 items
console.log(
  exampleArray
    .filter(e => e > 4)
    .hasMoreThanTwoItems()
);

// false, filtering will result in zero items
console.log(
  exampleArray
    .filter(e => e > 10)
    .hasMoreThanTwoItems()
);

// true, is an ExampleArray
console.log(
  exampleArray
    .map(e => e * 2)
    .isExampleArray()
);
```

Note that there are also other Array methods which return arrays, including `splice`, `slice`, and (experimental) `flat` and `flatMap`. If you want those to return a custom class instantiation rather than the default `Array` instance, follow the same pattern: shadow the `Array.prototype` function name, and return a `new ExampleArray` populated with the result of `apply`ing the `Array.prototype` method:

```
<fnName>(...args) {
  return new ExampleArray(
    ...super.<fnName>.apply(this, args)
  );
}
```

Comment: As I noted in my answer, the shadow methods aren't necessary.  You will get the same results without them.  I didn't try the other functions (slice, etc), but pretty sure they should all work as well.

Comment: To make this more DRY, you might want to write a helper function that creates all the wrapper methods.

Comment: I must apologize, your solution is correct. I didn't realize at the time because of an oversight using docker.

Answer (score 6):

You don't need to rewrite or override any of Array's methods.  Just make sure you have a proper constructor.

The reason why this works is in the ES6 spec [here](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-arrayspeciescreate) (emphasis added):

> 9.4.2.3 ArraySpeciesCreate(originalArray, length)
>
> ...
>
> Let C be ***Get(originalArray, "constructor").*** ReturnIfAbrupt(C). If
>   IsConstructor(C) is true, then
>
> ...

This is what `Array.filter` uses to create the new array - it gets the constructor of the original object and uses that to construct the filtered array.

Here is the code from another answer with the redefined filter and map methods removed, and it works the same way without them.  This code (using Chrome's console):

```
class ExampleArray extends Array {
  constructor(...args) {
    super(...args);
  }
  hasMoreThanTwoItems() {
    // example custom method
    return this.length > 2;
  }
  isExampleArray() {
    return true;
  }
}

const exampleArray = new ExampleArray(3, 4, 5, 6, 7);

// true, filtering will result in 3 items
console.log(
  exampleArray
    .filter(e => e > 4)
    .hasMoreThanTwoItems()
);

// false, filtering will result in zero items
console.log(
  exampleArray
    .filter(e => e > 10)
    .hasMoreThanTwoItems()
);

// true, is an ExampleArray
console.log(
  exampleArray
    .map(e => e * 2)
    .isExampleArray()
);
```

produces this output:

```
true
false
true
```

I must add, this is not a good model for extending javascript classes in general, but Array, apparently, is extensible by design.

Answer (score 0):

Much simpler is to create static functions that take any array as first argument.

That way the Array is still extended (feature wise). Also extending Array is confusing and does not scale in large teams. The constructor will also be lost whenever the array is transferred (for example JSON in HTTP request) without extra care.

Answer (score -1):

Create new method name filter, and use inside with the 'super' key word, like so: super.filter(func)

Comment: Not a big fan of this approach, but I would suggest, if you want to propose it, that you change the example prototype to match that of [Array.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)